# Sklearn validation_curve : Which possibilities do I have for the "param_name" parameter

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn

If I calculate the [validation curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve.html#sklearn.model_selection.validation_curve) like follows:

```
PolynomialRegression(degree=2,**kwargs):
    return make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree),LinearRegression(**kwargs))

#...

degree=np.arange(0,21)

train_score,val_score=validation_curve(PolynomialRegression(),X,y,"polynomialfeatures__degree",degree,cv=7)
```

the function claims the parameter "param_name" which is the name of the parameter that will be evaluated ("param_range") In this case it is polynomialfeatures__degree.
But:

1. From where do I get the string for "param_name" in general and from where do I get the string "polynomialfeatures__degree" in particular because I can't find this param_name in any documentation...Is the "function__param name" a common way to point on the param_name of a function??
2. For which estimators can I use the validation_curve function?

Comment: I tried to answer these question but not sure I got what you want to do. What is your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***PART 1***

***Answer to your question # 1:***

As `param_name` you can use one of the available parameters of the estimator of your choice.

For example: Let's say that you choose the estimator: `LinearRegression`. From this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) you can see than the available parameters/arguments are `fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=1`. So now you know what are the available parameters of the specific estimator.

Now, from [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-validation-curve-py) we can see how to define the `param_name` and `param_range`.

Part of the example in this link:

```
param_range = np.logspace(-6, -1, 5)

train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
SVC(), X, y, param_name="gamma", param_range=param_range,
cv=10, scoring="accuracy", n_jobs=1)
```

**EDIT 1**:

For the "string" as you call it: if I understand right you want to do something like:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

a= PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
a.get_params()
```

result:

```
{'include_bias': True, 'interaction_only': False, 'degree': 2}
```

These are the available **param_names** for the PolynomialFeatures.

**EDIT 2:**

Another way to see the `param_names` is to go to the source code.

For example, here [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L1139) you can see in lines 1149-1160 the strings of the parameters for the `PolynomialFeatures` estimator.

Finally, here [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L417) you can see in lines 421-444 the strings of the parameters for the `LinearRegression` estimator.

**EDIT 3:**

Other way to **get** and **set** the parameters of estimator in sklearn.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.get_params(deep=True)
```

result:

```
{'copy_X': True, 'normalize': False, 'n_jobs': 1, 'fit_intercept': True}
```

Now that you know the parameters you create your parameters:

```
params = {  'copy_X': False,  'fit_intercept': True,  'normalize': True }
```

And then you can unpack them in the estimator:

```
lr_new = LinearRegression(**params)
lr_new
```

result:

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=False, n_jobs=1, normalize=True)
```

***PART 2:***

***Answer to your question # 2:***

I think that in the case of `sklearn` module, you can use the `validation_curve` for all the estimators.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, that helped me much but there is still some uncertainty about the param_name parameter. I have edited my question

Comment: @2Obe What do you mean when you say "string"? I edited my answer adding a new small example. Is that what you need?

Comment: @ser...nearly. Now I understand from where I can get the param_names in general. BUT I can't find "polynomialfeatures__degree". Should this be another notation for ""Look at the polynomialfeatures function for the param_name "degree"? If so, is the "some function__param name at function" notation always the notation to call the "param_name" from an other function?

Comment: I see your point. In general there are examples and tutorials from sklearn website where you can see these notations (e.g. [link 1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) [link 2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_digits.html) ) I will check if there another way and let you know

Comment: I think my assumption with the  "some function__param name at function" were correct because also [here](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html) the author calls the param_name from another function with this spelling:                  `smote = os.SMOTE(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)                                                                                            
                      ms.validation_curve(
    pipeline, X, y, param_name="smote__k_neighbors", #.....further parameters....#)`

Comment: @2Obe  yes i agree. From here [link](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/_modules/imblearn/over_sampling/smote.html#SMOTE) you can see again the k_neighbors parameter but not the smote__k_neighbors. I will check if there is another way today. However, also using Params ={'k_neighbots'=10} and not necessary Params = {'smote__k_neigbors'=10} should work.

Comment: Yes thats right, BUT: k_neighbors is a parameter of SMOTE, but SMOTE is not directly incorporated as estimator into the validation_curve function. That is you have to "call" the k_neighbors parameter via: smote__k_neigbors. If you directly incorporate an estimator like for example SVC you can directly call the param_name with degree.... `validation_curve(SVC,X,y,param_name"degree",#...........#)`

Comment: @2Obe Yes, I am talking only for sklearn estimators. SMOTE is not from sklearn. If I find any other solution I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

`polynomialfeatures__degree` is one of the parameters of the function `PolynomialRegression()`. You can get the list of parameters like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

def PolynomialRegression(degree=2, **kwargs):
    return make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree),
                         LinearRegression(**kwargs))

a = PolynomialRegression()
a.get_params()
```

### Result

```
{'memory': None,
 'steps': [('polynomialfeatures', PolynomialFeatures()),
  ('linearregression', LinearRegression())],
 'verbose': False,
 'polynomialfeatures': PolynomialFeatures(),
 'linearregression': LinearRegression(),
 'polynomialfeatures__degree': 2,
 'polynomialfeatures__include_bias': True,
 'polynomialfeatures__interaction_only': False,
 'polynomialfeatures__order': 'C',
 'linearregression__copy_X': True,
 'linearregression__fit_intercept': True,
 'linearregression__n_jobs': None,
 'linearregression__normalize': 'deprecated',
 'linearregression__positive': False}
```

The parameter is set to a default value of 2. This value will be varied by the `validation_curve()` function